# Можно в IntelliJ IDEA посмотреть где используется перегруженный метод?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Можно посмотреть, где используется метод, нажатием комбинации клавиш ctrl + ЛКМ (с наведенным на метод курсором), но если это @override метод, мы увидим ссылки на **все** вызовы метода с таким названием, а не конкретно того, которого хотим. Можно ли как-то посмотреть, где используется конкретный метод?

Comment: Попробуйте Ctrl+Space. Или же можно показать перегруженные конструкторы, включив скрытую опцию. Вызовите пункт меню Help | Find Action и введите Registry, чтобы перейти в реестр. Здесь включите опцию java.completion.show.constructors.

Comment: ЕМНИП, Alt+F7 показывает либо все usages с иерархией, либо только конкретный метод, если на нем @Override стоит

Answer (score 0):

Что то из этого подойдет... и используйте дебаг, чтобы понять какой именно метод вызывается....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]